# How can I filter all values in a CSV spreadsheet that don't match one of hundreds of values from another spreadsheet?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Google Sheets and Google Collab together and trying to clean up the data I've downloaded as a CSV file. The problem I'm facing is that I want to filter out all results that don't match one of 100+ values one could have as group names which I've grabbed from another spreadsheet and currently have stored in an array. I think there are one or two other filters I'll want to apply, but the others only have four or five possible values in comparison.

Comment: I'm thinking I might be able to use this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

```class_23 = titanic[titanic["Pclass"].isin([2, 3])]```

Of course instead of [2,3] I'm assuming I can put a whole array. I don't yet know how to use Pandas so I'm assuming I've got to import pandas and find some way to put the google sheets data into Pandas. That part seems easier to me than what I was asking as I assume finding examples won't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded using Pandas `isin()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Specifically I used something like the example here:

```
titanic[titanic["Pclass"].isin([2, 3])]
```

I understand `isin()` provided you with booleans telling you whether an index is in the array. Using it like above turns it into a filter of sorts only keeping the items that match the items in the array.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html